# Is it possible to create a Qt customer widget *in* designer *for* designer?

Tags: qt, widget

I have found a really neat custom widget for Qt and managed to incorporate it into Qt Designer. I would now like to create a customer widget *in* designer by placing 32 of these LEDs into a new widget *in* Designer, then add some functions to it such as giving it address and passing data into it that will then illuminate patterns in colours according to the passed data.

My questions are:

1. Can I do this? I have placed 32 LEDs on to a new QFrame widget in designer and named the LEDs 0-31, but am at a loss as to know what to do next.
2. Is there a tutorial anywhere for this? I have found loads of hits on google for creating custom widgets *for* designer, but not *using* designer.

Please bear in mind I am not a good Qt programmer, I write embedded code for micros in C and am really not good at object orientated code; I can just hack together relatively simple programs for test and measurement. I need something that will hand hold me through this.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-worldtimeclockplugin-example.html

This seemed to be the kind of thing I wanted, it seemed to look like someone has placed widgets on a screen to create a new widget, but it seems to keep referring back to Creator.

Maybe I am trying to do something impossible. Maybe I have to place this new LED in creator with code?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. A Designer plugin basically consists of 2 Parts:

- The Widget that you want to add to the designer
- The plugin itself that provides information about the widget usw.

You can simply create the widget with the designer, add the `QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT` macro and thats it. Create your designer plugin to load this widget and it should work.

**Note:** Since you mentioned your not very experienced, you should try to follow the [Custom Widget Plugin Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-customwidgetplugin-example.html). Once you understood that one, it's only a small step to your designed plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I'd seen this, but I don't follow it at all. Even down to things like it saying: "We subclass QWidget...". I assume that means in Qt Creator, but exactly how you start I don't know. 

In the little example you typed, I have no idea at all where to add this QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT or how and where to add functions for things like how to give it an address, how to pass a pointer to data for it to process etc. 

Were I creating a class in Creator I could do the latter, but I just can't make this leap to knit the two together.

Comment: Well, creating your own designer plugin is not exactly something suited for beginners in C++/Qt... You should check out some tutorials and just build the Qt example on your own, maybe modify it to get a better understanding of the plugin system. Creating plugins is no different from normal programs, except that instead of a main you have your plugin-class - rigth know I don't have the time for a full example - but if you can't figure it out until the weekend, I migth find the time...